# Get one portion of text given another portion (PHP)

Tags: php, string

I've mapped routing numbers to bank names with one problem: I can't figure out how to get only the bank name and **not** the bank name + a portion of its address. I realize I've set [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get 35 characters but I didn't know it would ignore spaces and fill the 35 length requirement with the next characters in the string (in this case the address).

Am I missing something obvious here? Should I not be using `substr()`?

```
//routing number, position: 0-9
//bank name, position: 35-70

$str="011000015O0110000150020802000000000FEDERAL RESERVE BANK                1000 PEACHTREE ST N.E.              ATLANTA             GA303094470866234568111     
011000028O0110000151072811000000000STATE STREET BANK AND TRUST COMPANY JAB2NW                              N. QUINCY           MA021710000617664240011     
011000138O0110000151101310000000000BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.               8001 VILLA PARK DRIVE               HENRICO             VA232280000800446013511     
011000206O0110000151072505000000000BANK OF AMERICA N.A                 PO BOX 27025                        RICHMOND            VA232617025800446013511     
011000390O0110000151072505000000000BANK OF AMERICA N.A                 PO BOX 27025                        RICHMOND            VA232617025800446013511     ";


            $arr=str_split($str, 157);

            echo '<br>';
            echo 'routing:'.substr($arr[0], 0, 9);
            echo 'name:'.substr($arr[0], 35, 70);


            echo '<br>';
            echo 'routing:'.substr($arr[1], 0, 9);
            echo 'name:'.substr($arr[1], 35, 70);


            echo '<br>';
            echo 'routing:'.substr($arr[2], 0, 9);
            echo 'name:'.substr($arr[2], 35, 70);


            echo '<br>';
            echo 'routing:'.substr($arr[3], 0, 9);
            echo 'name:'.substr($arr[3], 35, 70);
```

Result:

```
routing:011000015name:FEDERAL RESERVE BANK 1000 PEACHTREE ST N.E. 
routing:011000028name:STATE STREET BANK AND TRUST COMPANY JAB2NW 
routing:011000138name:BANK OF AMERICA, N.A. 8001 VILLA PARK DRIVE 
routing:011000206name:BANK OF AMERICA N.A PO BOX 27025
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm an idiot, I misunderstood how `substr()` works.

The length parameter should be `35` and not `70`. My brain was thinking in terms of a range.

So this:

```
echo 'name:'.substr($arr[2], 35, 35);
```

and not this:

```
echo 'name:'.substr($arr[2], 35, 70);
```

Comment: You may want to also use trim() to account for additional spaces a blind substr() will pull. Ex: $name = trim(substr( $arr[2], 35, 35));